# Add new coloumn in design view failed

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a DB table.This table has a data(Already data in that table).I wanted to add new coloumns to the database.I tried it in using Design View but CANT.Is there any way to do it.. Need to Change Coloumna name & SPECIALLY add new coloumns.. No data loss.

DB - SQL SERVER 2008 R2

I tried to add Name filed,thats NULL

[image: img]

When i go to SAVE it,i got this error

[image: error]

Comment: If your new column has a constraint of NOT NULL and then you can't. You should be able to add new column by selecting allow null option.

Comment: You can add a non nullable field as long as you set a default constraint

Comment: @BishnuPaudel Yes NULL fields.but cant know

Comment: Don't use the design view - it doesn't take long to learn to enter `ALTER TABLE User_1 add Name varchar(50) null` in a query window...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Then not effect to my another coloumns data know ?

Comment: This message usually happens if you try and create the new column between other columns rather than positioned at the end of the table. You can turn the setting to disallow these changes off in the options but best just to use TSQL for this as per @Damien_The_Unbeliever's comment.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever problem solved from your answer

Answer (score 1):

there is an option in Sql Management Studio that disables this safety mechanism, as the alert message says.

Tools --> Options --> Designers --> Table and Database Designers
uncheck "Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation".

You can of course always use ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN